# Spring transaction whit several operations and rollback

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, rollback

I have to write some methods to change values into database and make some operations on file system.
So I have to make this sequence of step:

1. Set the boolean `Updating` field to `true` into database. It is used to avoid access to file system and database information that are linked with this value (for example a fleet of cars)
2. Make some operation on the database. For example change the date, name, value or other fields. These changes affect more database tables.
3. Make change to file system and database
4. Set the boolean `Updating` to false

As you can imagine I have to manage errors and start rollback procedure to restore database and file system.
I have some doubt about how I can write my method. I have:

- The entity
- The repository interface that extends `JpaRepository`and has Query creation from method names and `@Query` annotated with `@Transactional` if them write into database (otherwise I recevied error)
- The service interface
- The service implementation that contains all the method to make simple changes to database. This class is annotated with `@Transactional`

From the other classes I call service methods to use database but if I call some of these methods I write each value into database so it isn't possible to throw rollback, or I wrong?
The step 1 has to be write immediatly into database instead the other changes should be use @Transactional properties, but just adding @Transactional to my method is enough? For file system rollback I create a backup of all subfolders and restore them in case of error.
For example:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=FileSystemException.class)
private void changeDisplacement(int idApplication, int idDisplacement){
    applicationServices.setUpdating(true); //this has be to write immediatly into database so that the other methods can stop using this application
    Application application = applicationServices.getId(idApplication);
    application.setDisplacement(displacementServices.getId(idDisplacement));

    //OTHER OPERATIONS ON DIFFERENT TABLES

    //OPERATIONS ON FILE SYSTEM CATCHING ALL EXCEPTION WITH TRY-CATCH AND IN THE CATCH RESTORE FILESYSTEM AND THROW FileSystemException to start database rollback
    //In the finally clause use applicationServices.setUpdating(false)  
}
```

Can it work with this logic or the `@Transactional` field is wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: I think that you cannot guarantees the _FILE RESTORE_ phase, is an exception is thrown while writing a file there's an high probability that writing it again,to restore it's state, will fail too.

Comment: sure, I'll try to update only one time, if the restore fails I send email and keep the file system locked until a manual operation fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` is OK here. The only thing is you need to set propagation of `applicationServices.setUpdating` to `REQUIRES_NEW` so that it gets committed individually:

```
public class ApplicationServices {
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void setUpdating(boolean b) {
        // update DB here
    }
}
```

In the case of the exceptions, it will still update the DB as long as you have the call to `setUpdating` in the finally block.

Comment: Thanks, this annotation creates a new transaction stopping temporary the main transaction, right? So if a method annotated with `@Transactional` calls other methods with the same annotation then the values into database are written only at the and of the main annotation?

Comment: `setUpdating` method uses a new TX with no dependency on the caller method's transaction. If the operation is successful, it will commit and other TX's will see the data.

Comment: perfect, and for the second part of question is how I had thought?

Comment: If by the second part you mean rolling back the filesystem, you will have to do it yourself. Spring transactions have no clue of filesystem operations you do.

Comment: I meant the case when a method annotated with @Transactional calls other methods with the same annotation, are the values into database written only at the end of the main annotation?

Comment: OIC, yes, if you don't specify propagations, they all share the same TX and TX gets committed after the outermost method finishes.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple questions here and some of them are hard to grasp, here is a bit of input. When you have this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=FileSystemException.class)
private void changeDisplacement(int idApplication, int idDisplacement){
    applicationServices.setUpdating(true);
```

That flag will hit the database only when the `@Transactional` finishes. The change stays in hibernate context, until the end of `@Transactionl` method.

So while you execute `changeDisplacement` and someone else comes and reads that flag - it will see false (because you have not written it to the DB just yet). You could get it via `READ_UNCOMMITTED`, but it's up to your application if you allow this.

You could have a method with `REQUIRES_NEW` and set that flag to true there and in case of revert update that flag back.

Generally updating both the DB and file system is not easy (keeping them in sync). The way I have done it before (might be better options) is register events (once a correct DB was made) and then write to the filesystem.

Comment: thanks for you advice. Yes the setUpdating has to be manually reverted. It's very difficult to keep syncronization between  database and file system expecially because the requirements were different at the moment of database design.